# Вопрос по подсветке div'ов прижатых друг к другу

Tags: html, css, hover

При наведении на блок хочу, чтобы он подсвечивался со всех сторон, а это не получается, потому что соседние блоки накладываются на подсветку ( на снимке снизу и слева ).
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```css
#square {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  float: left;
  background-color: red;
}
#square:hover {
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 10px #F0FFF0;
}
#workspace {
  width: 800px;
  height: 1200px;
  background-color: white;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  margin-top: 20px;
}
```

```html
<div id="workspace">
  <div id="square"></div>
  <div id="square"></div>
  <div id="square"></div>
  ...
  <div id="square"></div>
  <div id="square"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: `id` должен быть уникальным. Для повторения стилей используют  классы.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
box-shadow: 0px 0px 20px #F0FFF0 inset;
```

[пример](https://jsfiddle.net/CRafT/55jphLx8/)

Answer (score 1):

Добавь:

```
    #square {
        z-index: 0;
        position: relative;
    }

    #square:hover {
        z-index: 1;
    }
```

PS: по моему id использовать плохая идея, лучше делать классы.

Comment: вообще ид использовать, ето ошыбка, на каждой отдельной странице нельзя чтоб дублировались айдишки, айди должен быть уникальным...